# How to render from backend Django MarkdownX to html for Vue.js front-end?

Tags: html, django, vue.js, markdown, render

I need to pass a field `description` in admin Django with Markdownx to an HTML to show in the front of `Vue.js`.
 I don’t know how to do it and I didn’t find anything about that.

Comment: Do you look for server-side rendering? If so, you can try [Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/)? If you ask for a more specific detail, please share your code etc. to make it clearer.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and learn how to create a [mcve]. You need to show us what you've tried and put some amount of effort in trying to resolve this yourself. Btw, what does vuejs have anything to do with it, rendering a field in and HTML template is depending on the javascript framework you use.